# Passing a valid path to Python from PHP

Tags: php, python

I have a Python program that parses files, takes a path as and argument and parses all files in the given path and all sub directories - using `os.walk(path)`. I want to call this from my php Web App, so the user can specify a path, which is then passed as an argument to the parser. (Passing a path is ok because its all on an internal network).

I can call the parser fine and pass the arguments ok using `popen()`, but the path that the Python program receives is always invalid. I have had the php script output the command it is sending to the browser. If I copy and paste that command into a command window, the parser works fine.

I know the path the php script passes is invalid from the result of `os.path.exists(path)` in the Python script

This is the code to call the Python program:

```
$path = $_REQUEST['location'];
echo "Path given is: ".$path;
$command = 'python C:\Workspaces\parsers\src\main\main.py '. intval($mode).'  "'.$path.'"';
echo "<p>".$command."</p>";
$parser = popen($command, 'r');
if ($parser){
  echo "<p>Ran the program</p>";
  while (!feof($parser)){
    $read = fgets($parser);
    if (!$read)
      echo "<p>Reached end of file</p>";        
      else
        echo "<p>".$read."</p>";                 
    }
  }
```

The command echoed in the browser is like:

`python C:\Workspaces\parsers\src\main\main.py 2 "I:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3"`

Where the 2 is just another argument to the script and `$_REQUEST['location']` is defined from an input text box in a form on the calling page.

This is on a Windows system, so I am assuming this has something to do with the backslashes in the path.

Basically, I am unsure as to how all the backslashes are being handled. I would like to understand how strings containing backslashes are sent to the php page, and how they are sent again using `popen()`. I think the result being printed to the browser is not the raw command string, and I can't be sure how many backslashes are really in the command being issued by popen().

If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate it.

Edit:

So in the Python program the path is used as follows:

```
 nfiles=0
 print 'Parsing all files in directory tree '+path+"<br />"
 start = time.time()
 if not os.path.exists(path):
   print "<p>Path is NOT REAL!!!</p>"
 else:
   print "<p>Path IS real!</p>"
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
   for f in files:
     file = os.path.join(root,f)
     print file
     nfiles+=1
     ...Code to run parser...
 print nfiles, "Files parsed<br />"
```

This is echoed back to the browser from the $read variable.

Output of that is:

```
Parsing all files in directory tree I:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3
Path is NOT REAL!!!

0 Files parsed
```

This is identical to the output if the command is run from the command line (the command being copied from the browser and pasted into the cmd window). EXCEPT, when run that way the path IS real, and all the files are parsed. (and in the command window the html markup shows too)

The web server and parsers are hosted on my local machine.

Comment: Could you add the error message from python? And get python to print out the path it recieves? From what I can tell, your echo debugging is top notch. Your command is correct. Now, depending on how you run PHP, maybe the path really is invalid. Is the drive "I:" on the client or on the server? Because, well, it *has* to be on the server for this to work...

Comment: You _should_ be alright with the backslashes as `$command` is a string literal (defined by using apostrophes rather than quote marks) - you could try to validate the path in PHP with `realpath()` before passing it to the Python pipe? Maybe also closing the pipe at the end with `pclose($parser)`...

Comment: Try printing out the path in the Python program to see what it actually receives.

Comment: What actually is `I:`? If it is a network drive, I have had all sorts of problems with getting this to work (never tried in Python but PHP and Java both don't like it). If this is the case, try using a full UNC of `\\servername\sharename` instead of the drive letter. Back slashes shouldn't be a problem, anything in `$_REQUEST` will be literal - escape sequences won;t be interpollated.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I edited my question to show Python code and output. I:\ is a network drive. And as I said, it works fine when called from the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see what user the PHP server is running as. If `I:\` is a network drive, don't expect those to be mapped under that user. Use a UNC path instead.

Things to try:

- a different path (we know `C:\Workspaces\parsers\src\main\` works, why don't you try that?)

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius! Have checked with the `C:\bla\bla` and it works. Will check with a UNC path for `I:\` and get back with results...

Comment: I have tried with a known good UNC path to `I:\`, but I still get the same error. Now I'm thinking this may be to do with folder privileges. Is there a way I can get PHP to print out what user it is running as?

Comment: Not solved yet. But I'm reasonably confident that this is the right answer, so I'm marking it as such. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Try looking through the `phpinfo()` stuff - I think the user should show up there. For the rest of the privileges stuff: I'm sorry, I don't really understand them myself :(